Audio Input not working on Dell Inspiron 5445, Ubuntu 22.04
Audio Input is not working in Ubuntu 22.04.5 in my newly bought Laptop ( Dell Inspiron 14 5445). Audio output is working fine. And the Audio Input is working fine in Windows 11 (Dual
Boot).
I tried with OBS studio, Audio Recorder, Sound Recorder. Audio Input is not working for any of them. What could be the reason?
Following is the output of neofetch.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64 
Host: Inspiron 14 5445 1.2.0 
Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic 
Uptime: 4 hours, 56 mins 
Packages: 1925 (dpkg), 15 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1200
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 8840U w/ Radeon 780M Graphics (16) @ 3.300GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Device 1900 
Memory: 4253MiB / 15286MiB 

Sound System Settings:

Sound System Settings while using OBS Studio:

Output of lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e8
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e9
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ee
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ea
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14eb
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14f7
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a80f
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1900 (rev c0)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c7
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b9
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ba
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 63)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
03:00.7 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 164a
04:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
04:00.1 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1502
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14ec
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c0
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15c1

Audio related output of lspci -v
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0ca8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at 606c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 63)
    Subsystem: Dell Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67, IOMMU group 19
    Memory at 60680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at 7d10000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_ps
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt, snd_sof_amd_vangogh, snd_sof_amd_acp63

03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Dell Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47, IOMMU group 20
    Memory at 606c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel


firmware-sof-signed is already installed.

Output of alsamixer:

Output of alsamixer > F4:

Output of pavucontrol (PulseAudio Volume Control):

